# Python: Pandas does not separate columns when reading tabular text file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a text file like this:

```
PERSONAL INFORMATION              

 First Name:             Michael
 Last Name:              Junior
 Birth Date:             May 17, 1999 
 Location:               Whitehurst Hall 301. City: Stillwater. State: OK
                         Taken on July 8, 2000 10:50:30 AM MST

WORK EXPERIENCE
Work type select                                        Part-time
ID number                                               10124
Company name                                            ABCDFG Inc.
Positions                                               Software Engineer/Research Scientist
                                                        Data Analyst/Scientist
```

As you could see the first column is feature names and the second column values. I read it using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


df=pd.read_table('personal.txt',skiprows=1)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',1000)
df
```

But it merges columns and outputs:

```
    PERSONAL INFORMATION
0   First Name: Michael
1   Last Name: Junior
2   Birth Date: May 17, 1999
3   Location: Whitehurst Hall 301. City: Stillwater. State: OK
4   Taken on July 8, 2000 10:50:30 AM MST
5   WORK EXPERIENCE
6   Work type select Part-time
7   ID number 10124
8   Company name Google Inc.
9   Positions Software Engineer/Research Scientist
10  Data Analyst/Scientist
```

I should escape from those titles PERSONAL INFORMATION and WORK EXPERIENCE as well. How can I read in a way that it gives me results appropriately in two columns?

Comment: ```pandas.read_table()``` reads in a file as if it was a structured data file like a csv. Basically because WORK EXPERIENCE is under PERSONAL INFORMATION and not to the right of it separated by a tab it will not be read in properly. Look into semi-structured files

Comment: i _hope_ the personal information here is not a real person's details

Comment: Of course, it is completely unreal. Just placeholders

Comment: not realy a task for pandas, the tata is not tabular

Comment: Could you show you code, please? Any help would be great!